# What does realloc do with the freed memory, if I can still read the content from another pointer after shrinkage with realloc?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

For numbers represented as cells grouped by four digits:

```
a = 15678
a = [5678][1] //according to indexing
```

This is a structure with dynamically allocated array of ints and int of length
I try to add two of them, a to b:

```
b = 0   //1 cell 
a = 15678  //2 cells
```

The functions which adds them is quite compliacted, but I can post the entire code if you wish. The essential:

```
void add(struct* a, struct* b) {
            struct* bigger;
            bigger = a; //if a has more cells
            //sum up
            ...
            *a = *bigger;
}
```

I want to set `a` to zero:

```
void clear(struct* a) {
      a->array = realloc(a->array, number_of_elements_in_define*sizeof(int));
      a->length = 1;
      a->array = 0;
}
```

However, if I want to print out `b` I got error:

```
==52293== Invalid read of size 4
==52293== at 0x10CC75: print_a_number (call5.c:355)
==52293== by 0x10D027: interpreter (call5.c:397)
==52293== by 0x10D35F: game (call5.c:453)
==52293== by 0x10D521: main (call5.c:496)
==52293== Address 0x58c6804 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 34 free'd
==52293== at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)
==52293== by 0x10CD65: clear (call5.c:367)
==52293== by 0x10D215: interpreter (call5.c:426)
==52293== by 0x10D35F: game (call5.c:453)
==52293== by 0x10D521: main (call5.c:496)
==52293== Block was alloc'd at
==52293== at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)
==52293== by 0x10B887: add (call5.c:117)
==52293== by 0x10D115: interpreter (call5.c:406)
==52293== by 0x10D35F: game (call5.c:453)
==52293== by 0x10D521: main (call5.c:496)
```

but after this error, the value is printed out.

It seems as if `b` has been still pointing to the freed memory, but why then it can be printed? How to prevent such a behaviour or change the code? I have tried:

```
struct copy = *bigger;
*a = copy;
```

but it doesn't change anything

I would appreciate your explanations and suggestions.

**EDIT**

**How to save the value for b, without accessing the freed memory?** I have tried using copying, but I didn't gave anything.

Here is the code which modifies b:

```
//help function
 int simple_add(int w, int m, int* p) {
     int number;
     int result = w + m + *p;
     if (result >= 10000) {
         *p = division(result);    //division by multiplication while p*i<=10000
         number = result - 10000*(*p);
     } else {
         number = result;
         *p = 0;
     }
     return number;
 }

 //problematic
 void add(numb* a, numb* b) {
     numb *big;
     numb *small;
     if (a->how_many != b->how_many) {
         small = min(a, b);  //simple min and max functions, not written for clarity
         big = max(a, b);
     } else {
         big = a;
         small = b;
     }

     int left = 0;

     int i = 0;
     while (i < small->how_many) {
         big->digits[i] = simple_add(big->digits[i], small->digits[i], &left);
         i++;
     }

     while (left != 0) {
         if (i == big->how_many) { 
             if ((size_t)i*NUM_INT*sizeof(int) >= sizeof(big->digits)) { 
                 int size;
                 if ((size_t)i*NUM_INT*sizeof(int) + 2 >= INT_MAX) size = INT_MAX-1;
                 else size = (size_t)i*NUM_INT*sizeof(int) + 2;
                 big->digits = realloc(big->digits, size);
             }
             big->digits[i++] = left;
             big->how_many++;
             pom = 0;
         } else {
             big->digits[i] = simple_add(big->digits[i], 0, &left);
             i++;
         }
     }
     *a = *big;
 }
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. You access already free'd memory

Comment: It is like tearing a piece of paper and throwing it in a bin.  You can still see what's written on it but you know sooner or later, the bin will be emptied and you cannot see it any more.  As you know, a rubbish bin is seldom emptied straight away.

Comment: I have to admit, that indeed cup explanation is beautiful, but I don't know, how to save the value for b...

Comment: Re “How to prevent such a behaviour or change the code?”: To prevent reading `b` after the memory for it has been freed, modify your code not to read from `b`. That is your job.

Comment: Re “How to save the value for b, without accessing the freed memory?”: If you want data saved, save it before freeing the memory it is in.

Comment: But how can I save the data, if I have tried using the copy of it and it didn't work?

Comment: Having a problem getting the data from `b` prior to changing its memory allocation would seem to be a different problem from the one you asked about in the title of this post. Prepare a [mre] and enter a new question with it.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc`, `realloc`, `free`, and related routines do not generally add memory to your processor or remove it. They may do these things incidentally, but their main job is to **manage reservations** of memory.

When you go to a bowling alley and rent a lane, they do not build a lane for you or bring one in from storage. In the old days, they just moved a marker around or move some token on a board or wrote a note on paper. That told them which lanes were in use, so they did not assign the lane to anybody else. And your job was to go to your lane and bowl in your lane, even though there was nothing preventing you from bowling in other lanes.

Memory management is the same way. When you call `malloc`, it makes a reservation and tells you what memory to use. When you call `realloc`, it changes that reservation. When you call `free`, it releases that reservation.

After the memory is no longer reserved for you, you are supposed to stop using it. You can try; it may still be there. But you might interfere with somebody else’s bowling.

Comment: Really good answer. I would upvote it twice if I could.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for an unclear question, but I could not have found then the exact reason of my problem to post it correctly.

If b was bigger than a, I have assigned a pointer bigger to b:

```
bigger = b;
```

Therefore, the block of memory pointed by `b` had two pointer indicating that: `bigger` and `b`.

After I proceed some operation on bigger, I assign the content of `bigger` to `a`:

```
*a = *b;
```

However, this block of memory is **still pointed also by** `b`. If I use free() on `b`, I do not free exactly `b` as a pointer - I free the block of memory pointed by both `a` and `b`. Therefore, if I want to use the content pointed by `a`, I reach for freed memory - freed in `free(b)`.

In case of the need to safely copy the content, I should do deep-copying, memcopy or change the function to work exactly on `a`, which I have done this time.